# External user cannot access SharePoint Extranet site (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users

I shared a SharePoint site with external user `abc@somebank.com`.

The external user got the invitation, but he clicked on the link in the email, he got error message saying

> External user access is blocked by their bank.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: check this one http://www.adrit.de/Blog/Post/25/External-sharing-with-Office-365---Part-2--How-to-share-SharePoint-content-with-external-users- ....if you still have the error, could you please share the complete error?

Comment: Hi, here is the complete description. I wanted to share a site with an external user. So for checking the functionality I shared the site with my gmail id. I created a microsoft account by associating my gmail to the microsoft account. When the site is shared with my gmail account, I got an email invitation, I clicked on the link and I could log into the site using my microsoft account details.. Later I wanted to try if the same procedure would work with one of our client who works in a bank. I asked him to create a microsoft account by associating using bank email id.

Comment: Later I shared the site with him, when he clicks on the link in the email, he gets an error that the site is blocked by their Bank security. Then I asked to copy paste the url of the site in the browser and try, he says he got an error saying site not available or is moved. But the site actually exists.

Comment: do they have the firewall on the network fromt heir the user accessing the site? May be network blocked that. can you ask user if he can try it from mobile or outof bank network. also add that site into the trusted zone

Comment: Thanks for the response I can try the options you just mentioned. I got a screenshot from the client when he tried to paste the url in the browser. It just says HTTP 403 Forbidden

Comment: for me it more close to the network or security issue.